Substitute elements of an array using JsonPath
I am using jsonpath-ng to substitute an element of an array. Given the yaml below:
paths
  /api/v1/chats:
    get:
      - name: other_chats
        in: query
        required: false
        type: boolean
      - name: status
        in: query
        required: false
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/ChatStatus'

I would like to have this output:
paths
  /api/v1/chats:
    get:
      - name: other_chats
        in: query
        required: false
        type: boolean
      - name: status
        in: query
        required: false
        type: string

I have tried:
all_of_expr = parse("$.paths.*.*.parameters[?(@.allOf)]")
all_of_elements = all_of_expr.find(openapi)
openapi = all_of_expr.update(openapi, {"type": "string"})

And I am getting:
paths
  /api/v1/chats:
    get:
      - name: other_chats
        in: query
        required: false
        type: boolean
      - type: string

If I try:
all_of_expr = parse("$.paths.*.*.parameters[*].allOf")
all_of_elements = all_of_expr.find(openapi)
openapi = all_of_expr.update(openapi, {"type": "string"})

paths
  /api/v1/chats:
    get:
      - name: other_chats
        in: query
        required: false
        type: boolean
      - name: status
        in: query
        required: false
        allOf:
          type: string


JSON Path is a query language.  It doesn't do transformations.

def remove_all_of(openapi):
    def remove_field_all_of(orig, data, field):
        del data[field]
        data[field]["type"] = "string"

    all_of_expr = parse("$.paths.*.*.parameters[?(@.allOf)]")
    openapi = all_of_expr.update(openapi, remove_field_all_of)
    return openapi

openapi = remove_all_of(openapi)

